# XuYF capacitor value notation

Tags: capacitor, schematics

I have stumbled upon such a notation for capacitor value in schematics (C35):

[image]

The C35 capacitor value is `4u7F`, whereas I am familiar with `4.7uF` notation. The former style I am only familiar for when used with resistors (i.e., `4k7`). Using such notation with caps seems odd to me, but at the same time I cannot rule out I am just ignorant to other form that is a so called standard and valid maybe.

I am not asking whether this format is correct maybe, as there is no strict rule here, but is it common?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substituting the SI prefix for the decimal separator is fairly common in electronics shorthand. At least in part, it can be attributed to how surface mount resistors were marked with limited available space (e.g. `4K7` for 4.7 kΩ).

Typically when such a substitution is done, the SI prefix (k for kilo, M for mega, etc.) is used in place of the decimal separator to save space, and the unit is omitted entirely, meant to be obvious in the context of the symbol or component to which the shorthand is applied. Using "R" for resistance is common when there is no SI prefix multiplier (e.g. `1R2` for 1.2 Ω).

With capacitors, where surface-mount ceramic ones don't normally have any marking, it can seem unusual to encounter this convention in schematics. I would argue that it is more common to see `4u7` instead of `4u7F` because by using the SI prefix as a decimal separator, it rather defeats the purpose (of shortening the label) to add the unit as a suffix.

My personal preference is to use `4.7 µF` in schematics, but because of the prevalence of the shorthand with resistors, I do sometimes use `4K7` in schematics.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I am familiar with using th described convention for resistor or voltage values- for the capacitor indeed it was confusing to see the unit in the end, as to match the notation, it would need to be `4u7` as mentioned...

Answer (score 3):

It is quite common to see SI prefixes used in lieu of decimal points. Particularly on older schematics, or in photocopies, small dots might get worn out and/or mistaken for printing artifacts. Having a clear and obvious letter in lieu of a decimal point makes reading mistakes less likely. Frequently the actual SI unit suffix (e.g. F, Ω) is dropped because it can be inferred from the schematic symbol or other context.

You've seen `2K2` resistors, `4U7` capacitors, `3V3` as a standard voltage, and also probably seen plenty of `10K` or `1M` resistors too (which are named under the same principle).

This is a convention that emerged in the US electronics industry and is not part of any official SI standard.

I personally prefer using capital letters -- `2K2` and not `2k2` -- because of potential confusion, especially for capacitance, between a `1m` and a `1n`.

Comment: Lower case "k" is proper for kilo. "M "means mega. "m" means milli.. Unfortunately not everyone follows the standards and so we must fish the meaning out of the context.

Comment: Proper, yes. But using a K or a k or a u or a U as a decimal point isn't proper -- this question isn't about what's "proper." For what it's worth, I've never come across a 1M capacitor, and for resistors, I'll break my own rule and write 100m. It's primarily for capacitors where a 1n may be mistaken for a 1m.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. Last time I actually needed a 100 mΩ resistor I marked it as 0R1. I've never needed a 100M to my knowledge but nonetheless, no confusion.

Comment: Ω is also frequently replaced with R due to lack of the symbol on typical typewriters and computers outside Greece, at least until recently. This, combined with the fact that 0.1~10 Ω resistors being much more common than 0.1~10 H inductors or 0.1~10 F capacitors, has led to R becoming the generic "no prefix" symbol in a few cases--I've seen the odd inductor marked as (or part-numbered as) something like 2R2 for a 2.2 H inductor. I'm not sure whether 2R2 or 2H2 would be more common here, but the latter certainly looks odd to my eye.